# PhalconPHP - Model returning empty data

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Recently, I've been working on a system using the Phalcon PHP framework. And up until now, it's been plain sailing.

I seem to be having an issue when pulling data from a MySQL database using a model. Everything else seems to be working fine, but a few fields are returning empty data despite there being data within those fields in the MySQL table.

After scanning the database itself, I can't seem to find the reason why these particular fields are empty because similar fields are returned with the data intact.

I've inserted the model data into an array to make it easier for me to browse it and find out what's going on, and this is the result:

```
[applications]    =>
    [application_id] => 5
    [application_user] => 1
    [application_servers] => skybuild
    [application_approved] => 
    [application_denied] => 
    [application_reviewed] => 
    [application_approvals] => 0
    [application_denials] => 0
    [application_date] => 1470739996
    [application_message] => This is just a test application to see whether the system is working.
[user]    =>
    [user_id] => 1
    [user_fname] => Leo
    [user_lname] => **********
    [user_birthday] => ****-**-**
    [user_email] => **********@**********.**.**
    [user_uname] => Leo_V117
    [user_upass] => ********************************
    [user_account] => ********-****-****-****-************
    [user_active] => Y
    [user_banned] => 
    [user_suspended] => 
    [user_registered] =>
```

The fields in question are:

- application

  - application_approved
  - application_denied
  - application_reviewed
- user

  - user_banned
  - user_suspended
  - user_registered

The question is:
**WHY** are these particular fields returning empty data and, ultimately, **HOW** can I go about fixing it.

## PHP Code

### Bootstrap

```
<?php ########################
##############################

use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {

    /**
     * Define some useful constants
     */
    define('BASE_DIR', dirname(__DIR__));
    define('APP_DIR', BASE_DIR . '/app');

    \Phalcon\Mvc\Model::setup(array(
        'notNullValidations' => false
    ));

    /**
     * Read the configuration
     */
    $config = include APP_DIR . '/config/config.php';

    /**
     * Read auto-loader
     */
    include APP_DIR . '/config/loader.php';

    /**
     * Read services
     */
    include APP_DIR . '/config/services.php';

    /**
     * Handle the request
     */
    $application = new Application($di);
    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ( $e->getMessage() );
    print_r ( nl2br( htmlentities( $e->getTraceAsString() ) ) );
    echo '</pre>';
}

##############################
########################### ?>
```

### Accounts

```
<?php ########################
##############################

namespace ProjectRogue\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness;

class Accounts extends Model {
    public $user_id;        // User ID

    public $user_fname;     // Field: First Name
    public $user_lname;     // Field: Last Name
    public $user_birthday;  // Field: Date of Birth
    public $user_email;     // Field: E-Mail
    public $user_uname;     // Field: Username
    public $user_upass;     // Field: Password
    public $user_account;   // Minecraft Account UUID

    public $user_active;    // Active
    public $user_banned;    // Banned
    public $user_suspended; // Suspended

    public $user_registered;

    public function beforeValidationOnCreate() {
        $this->user_active = 'N';
        $this->user_banned = 'N';
        $this->user_suspended = 'N';
        $this->user_code = $this->generateCode();
        $this->user_registered = time();
    }

    public function afterSave() {
        if( $this->user_active == 'N' ) {
            // Check E-Mail Status;
            $email = new EmailConfirmation();

            $email->email_user = $this->user_id;
            $email->email_code = $this->generateCode();
            $email->email_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

            if( $email->save() ) {
                $this->getDI()->getFlash()->notice('A confirmation E-Mail has been sent to '.$this->user_email);
            }

            // Send Commands;
            $service_servers = new ServiceServers();
            $service_commands = array();

            $servers = $service_servers::find();

            $json_response['data']['servers_size'] = count($servers);

            foreach( $servers as $server ) {
                $service_commands[ $server->server_id ] = new ServiceCommands();

                // Insert Data;
                $service_commands[ $server->server_id ]->assign(array(
                    'command_server'        =>  $server->server_token,
                    'command_body'          =>  'broadcast &6&l[player]&r &fhas just registered an account to our website!',
                    'command_player'        =>  $this->user_account,
                    'command_player_online' =>  'Y'
                ));

                // Save;
                $service_commands[ $server->server_id ]->save();
            }
        }
    }

    public function validation() {
        $this->validate(new Uniqueness(array(
            'field'         => 'user_uname',
            'message'       => 'This Username is already in use.'
        )));

        $this->validate(new Uniqueness(array(
            'field'         => 'user_email',
            'message'       => 'This E-Mail is already in use.'
        )));

        $this->validate(new Uniqueness(array(
            'field'         => 'user_account',
            'message'       => 'This Minecraft Account is already in use.'
        )));

        return $this->validationHasFailed() != true;
    }
}

##############################
########################### ?>
```

### ApplicationStaff

```
<?php ########################
##############################

namespace ProjectRogue\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness;

class ApplicationsStaff extends Model {
    public $application_id;         // Application ID;
    public $application_user;       // Application User;
    public $application_servers;    // Application Servers;
    public $application_approved;
    public $application_denied;
    public $application_reviewed;
    public $application_approvals;  // Application Approvals;
    public $application_denials;    // Application Denials;
    public $application_date;       // Application Date;
    public $application_message;    // Application Message;

    public function beforeValidationOnCreate() {
        $this->application_date = time();
        $this->application_approvals = 0;
        $this->application_denials = 0;

        $this->application_approved = "N";
        $this->application_denied = "N";
        $this->application_reviewed = "N";
    }

    public function validation() {
        return $this->validationHasFailed() != true;
    }
}

##############################
########################### ?>
```

Comment: What are the column types in the database? Are they perhaps Bool?

Comment: No.
application_approved, application_denied, application_reviewed, user_banned, and user_suspened are VARCHAR and return either **Y** or **N** - whereas user_registered is INT, returning a number.

Comment: I also updated the submission to include the code used in my Bootstrapper. I have the sneaking suspicion that that may be the culprit.

Comment: This is really strange. Can you try something like `$test = Accounts::findFirst(28); print_r($test->toArray());` Where 28 is the primary key of record where you are 100% sure there is data in the fields. Do so and see if the dump has the fields populated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120513/discussion-between-nikolay-mihaylov-and-leov117).

Answer (score 0):

It actually turns out that the data from each model was cached in my service. Deleting said cache forced the models to return the data as expected.